# Add extract fields to Django model serializer while doing validations

Tags: python, django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

Supposed I had the following model, and modelSerializer:

**models.py**

```
class Approve(models.Model):
    process = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Associated Process')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Approval Content")
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ApproveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Approve
        fields = ('id', 'process' ,'content')
    def validate(self, value):
        process = value['process']
        try:
            something_else = Something.objects.get(process)
        except Something.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid Process')
        return value
```

---

The thing is that I want to validate the incoming data in serializers.py, instead of views.py. You can notice that in order to make a validation check, I had query the database for **something_else**.

The problem is that I want to use this object *something_else* in the views.py, instead of making another database query. Is there any ways I can pass it with the serializer, without causing a serializer validation error when call serializer.is_valid() method.

---

Any suggestions will be welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using this data in the views? Can you show that code?

Comment: @Arundas R  I may want to change some attributes in **something_else** , and I don't want to make another database query.

Comment: You can override create method inside serializer instead of using it in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a way to address the problem.

**serializers.py**

```
class ApproveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Approve
        fields = ('id', 'process' ,'content')
    def validate(self, value):
        process = value['process']
        try:
            something_else = Something.objects.get(process)
            value['something_else'] = something_else
        except Something.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid Process')
        return value
```

**views.py**
Before calling the serializer.save() method, you should pop the value that had been added to the serializer.

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = ApproveSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        something_else = serializer.validated_data.pop('something_else')
        something_else.property = new_property
        something_else.save()
        serializer.save()
    else:
        # Error handling goes here serialzier.errors
```

Not sure this is a good practice, but at least it works for me right now. Hoping to know a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure how your `views.py` might look but essentially, you will need to instantiate the serializer there:

```
def approve_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        process = request.POST.get('value', None)
        something_else = Something.objects.filter(process=process).first()
        serializer = ApproveSerializer(something_else=something_else) # This is where you pass the something_else object. 
        if serializer.is_valid():
             # Your code for successful validation.
        else:
             # Your code for failed validation
```

Now that you have passed `something_else` into the `ApproveSerializer`, you need to set it up as a property:

```
class ApproveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, something_else=None):
        self.something_else = something_else

    class Meta:
        model = Approve
        fields = ('id', 'process' ,'content')

    def validate(self, value):
        process = value['process']
        if not self.something_else:
             raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid Process')
    return value
```

Comment: I am using DjangoRestFramework, so I am hopping to do the validation check all in the serializer. In my view function, I would use something like: `serializer = ApproveSerializer(data=request.data)`. Without accessing the  incoming data in the view directly.